# Putting data-index in Javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html form that has some fields generated by a js file. I'm trying to figure out how to add the "data-index" into the javascript code and I'm not finding any documentation on how to add it (maybe I'm googling the wrong things)

Here is a brief snippet of the code in the js file:

```
   const serialInput = createDomElement("input", "form-control")
            serialInput.name ="serial " + device_id
            serialInput.placeholder="10 characters"
            serialInput.required = true
            serialInput.className ="form-control"
            serialInput.minLength = "10"
            serialInput.maxLength = "10"
```

I need to add the `data-index="x"` to that code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what does `createDomElement("input", "form-control")` return? an input element with the class form-control?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
 const serialInput = document.createElement("input");
            serialInput.name ="serial 1";
            serialInput.placeholder="10 characters";
            serialInput.required = true;
            serialInput.className ="form-control";
            serialInput.minLength = "10";
            serialInput.maxLength = "10";
            serialInput.setAttribute("data-index","x");
            
            console.log(serialInput);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
serialInput.setAttribute('data-index', 'x');
//or
serialInput.dataset.index = 'x';
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like adding this to your js:

```
serialInput.dataset.index = "the index"
```

See the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)